# How to fix Assignment in condition error in php?

Tags: php, while-loop, syntax-error, assignment-operator

I have this code:

```
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($ethnicity)) {
    if ($val == '')
        $ethnicity = '';
    break;
}
```

and I get an error saying: `Assignment in condition, Change to ==`

But I can't change it to `==` or it's not working.

Anyone care to explain to me why this is happening?

edit.

the error is for the first line.

also i get the same error here:

```
             while (($row = mysql_fetch_row ($result)))
            {   
             $sms_providerchecked0= $row[3];
             $to_return_email12 = $cell."@$sms0";
            }
```

in the first line

Comment: can you explain what you're doing with this line.

while (list ($key, $val) = each ($ethnicity))

Comment: what line is it throwing that error on? (first line?) and why are you going through a loop if you're just going to break the first time through the loop?

Comment: So basically if any value in the $ethnicity array is empty, then nuke the whole array and change it to an empty string? Man, if stores did that anytime they found an empty box on the shelves, there wouldn't be many stores left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ( false!=(list($key, $val)=each($ethnicity)) ) {
```

I don't have zend studio so this might or might not do the trick...

Answer (score 2):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
while ($row) {   
    $sms_providerchecked0= $row[3];
    $to_return_email12 = $cell."@$sms0";
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting an extra set or parentheses around the condition?

IE:

```
while ((list ($key, $val) = each ($ethnicity))) 
{
    if ($val == '')
    $ethnicity = '';
    break;
}
```

Also, what IDE are you using, as this very likely could just be a problem with your IDE being overzealous about preventing *unintentional* assignments in condition.

**EDIT:**

As you are using zend, and your code is perfectly valid, it looks like if you want to stop seeing the warning so that you can write your code the way that you want to(this is an erroneous warning), you can disable that warning in 
**Window | Preferences, PHP | Semantic Analysis.**

Comment: the extra parentheses didn't help. I'm using zend studio

Comment: I am reading in a lot of places that this is a big problem with zend. I've edited the answer above, please check.

Comment: thanks, as well, looks like the sin tax @volkerk give is running OK

Comment: that's good, just remember that what you originally had IS valid and it's the normal way a lot of people do it, Zend just has a small issue with that. Your code would still have worked perfectly fine, you could just ignore the warning or disable it, as PHP itself is fine with assignment in condition.